Question about Hungarian algorithm

Why we could do that?
Rs and Rt could contain multiple edges
i e Rt 3->2 3->4 then it is not M

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

I think you should try to reformulate your problem. The drawing is messy and I don't really see where you are going at.
